# How to make CartThrob PayPal Gateway redirect to German PayPal site?

Tags: cartthrob, paypal, payment-gateway, language

We are using the `Cartthrob_paypal_express.php` Payment Gateway with CartThrob for over a year now and it is working great.

Just yesterday I noticed that users are being taken to the English version of PayPal when clicking "Purchase". In the top right there is a language dropdown select with English, French and Spanish I believe but not German.

Logging in an purchasing works nonetheless but I would like to have the users land on the German language version since we are a German shop.

I called PayPal today but all they could tell me was that it must have something to do with the payment gateway plugin. I skimmed through the php file but couldn't find anything really (not good with php).

In the CT prefs I also coudn't find anything. Also the API username and stuff doesn't give me a clue.

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an input for language to your checkout form should set paypal's localecode.

```
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="DE" />
```

Comment: Thanks Barrett, this is working great. One additional step that would make this truly awesome would be to set  the language dynamically based on the users browser language. Do you have an idea for something like this?

Comment: Nevermind Barrett. I realized that my additional question is not appropriate in this context here. I'll check other sources. Thanks again for the correct answer to my question.